# Problems with rendering after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 on Chromebook Acer C720

Tags: intel-graphics, chromebook

Today I upgraded my Chrubuntu (Ubuntu 13.13) to Ubuntu 14.04 using the do-release-upgrade script.

```
user@chrubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty
```

Everything went fine, also the trackball works after a kernel patch. However, the video card is quite slow and I can't watch any videos in VLC properly anymore. I think the reason is the missing rendering:

With:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

I get:

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.0
 **Not software rendered: no**
Not blacklisted: yes
GLX fbconfig: yes
GLX texture from pixmap: yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program: yes
GL fragment program: yes
GL vertex buffer object: yes
GL framebuffer object: yes
GL version is 1.4+: yes
**Unity 3D supported: no**
```

Some further information on my system:

```
lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

uname -a

Linux chrubuntu 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`xserver-xorg-video-intel` is installed.

How can I install `Mesa DRI Intel` as renderer or fix the problem to watch videos again in fullscreen in VLC?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your user has access to `/dev/dri/*`. You might have to add yourself to the `video` group.